# C# execute, wait, read command's output

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, process

I'm trying to read all system information on a windows pc, using C#. Here is my code :

```
 public static string GetSystemInfo()
        {
            String command = "systeminfo";
            ProcessStartInfo cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            cmdsi.Arguments = command;
            Process cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            return cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

But it just opens a console, doesn't execute `systeminfo` command.

**How this can be solved?**

Comment: Add the /C parameter, `String command = "/C systeminfo";`, this will start the right program at least.

Comment: `RedirectStandardOutput` must be set to `true`, as well as output must be read before `WaitForExit`, otherwise it can cause a deadlock, please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following snippet will work

```cs
public static string GetSystemInfo()
{
    var command = "/c systeminfo";
    var cmdsi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    cmdsi.Arguments = command;
    cmdsi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmdsi.UseShellExecute = false;
    var cmd = Process.Start(cmdsi);
    var output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    cmd.WaitForExit();

    return output;
}
```

You should set `RedirectStandardOutput` to `true` and read output before calling `WaitForExit`, otherwise you can get a deadlock, per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netframework-4.8)

> The example avoids a deadlock condition by calling
>   `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` before `p.WaitForExit`. A deadlock condition
>   can result if the parent process calls `p.WaitForExit` before
>   `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` and the child process writes enough text to
>   fill the redirected stream. The parent process would wait indefinitely
>   for the child process to exit.

`/c` means terminating command line after execution

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend `"/c"` to the command

```
String command = "/c systeminfo";
```

`/c` indicates that you want to execute a command that follows

**Update**

`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` needs to be set to true as mentioned in Pavel's Answer.

Comment: it solved the problem partially, in `cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` it would get an error. @pavel solved it using `RedirectStandardOutput`